# How to structure a given varable coming from JSON to C#

Tags: c#, json

How would i structure the "location" variable coming from a XML Message. to look like the rest of the C# class written to parse the XML message.

```
public class PlayerState
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    double u { get; set; }
    double v { get; set; }
    ....
    ..
}
```

```
<PlayerState Version="int" Series="something">
<ID>int</ID>
<u>30.12</u>
<v>-7.301726E-15</v>
<Location>
         <LocationPlayer Version="int" Series="Something">
            <Lat>double</Lat>
            <Long>double</Long>
            <Alt>double</Alt>
            <AltType>MSL</AltType>
         </LocationPlayer>
</Location>
```

Comment: That looks like maybe it's XML, not JSON.

Comment: I agree this looks like XML rather than JSON, but your question still makes sense. I think you want `Location` to be a `List<LocationPlayer>`. You would also create a `LocationPlayer` class that has `Lat`, `Long`, `Alt`, and `AltType`.

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerState));
using (var reader = new StreamReader(yourXml))
{
    PlayerState ps  = (PlayerState)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Remember to make your class's properties public too, or they wont be accessible to the serializer.